# Dual-boot Windows 7 Ultimate 64-bit and Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS 64-bit on Crucial MX100 512GB SSD

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, partitioning, windows-7, ssd

Good evening all,

I trust you are well.

This is my first time on AskUbuntu, the first time I ask something. Nice to meet you all.

I have some questions and I hope you can help me find the answers.

I have been doing some maintenance work on my laptop, i.e. cleaning, replacing, upgrading, and I decided that it is time for me to get to know Linux.

I purchased a Crucial MX100 512GB SSD to replace my old WD HDD and, I must admit, I am already in love with the flash memory: it's super fast!

I now wish to install Windows 7 Ultimate 64-bit and Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS 64-bit on my SSD. This is going to be a clean install, so I can do whatever I want to do. The SSD is the only storage drive I have installed.

As I previously mentioned, I am new to Ubuntu - I am now looking for some guidance and help in order to get the dual-boot working.

I own a HP Pavilion dv6500 laptop, with 4GB RAM installed.

I will be using Windows primarily, Ubuntu is going to be a learning experience only, but I intend to keep it installed and use it more in future.

I don't know how to set the partitions properly, this is where I need your help. I have been reading many topics, posts and articles about this but I couldn't find an SSD-only, specific, step-by-step instruction. The ones I found were SSD and HDD related and I got confused. My apologies.

I am currently waiting for Ubuntu media (DVD and USB key) from a OSDisc.com delivery. I only have the Windows installation disc with me.

Can I install Windows while I wait for the Ubuntu delivery? Do I need to do anything on the SSD before the Windows installation? Do I need to do a Custom Windows installation and set the partitions from the initial wizard? If so, can you tell me, more or less, the different partitions I need to create? The SSD is brand new, I only installed Windows for testing but I can do it again.

Please, let me know if you require additional information from me.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Thank you very much in advance.

PS: I don't play games on my laptop.

Comment: Install Windows first then install Ubuntu. it not more complicated than that. Follow the live-install it will guide you well.

Comment: Windows will default to use entire drive. You should use Windows partition tools to shrink the Windows partition to make space for Ubuntu, not not to create any new partitions. Reboot Windows before installing Ubuntu so it can run chkdsk. You may also want a shared NTFS data partition for any data you may want in either system. Best not to use Ubuntu to write into Windows system partition but ok to read from it. And Windows will not see the Linux partitions.

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to install Ubuntu alongside Windows 7 then there is no need to wait for Ubuntu. You can go ahead and install Windows 7 on the hard drive and when you install Ubuntu 14.04 make sure you choose 'Install Ubuntu alongside Windows 7' and at that point you can set the size of the Linux partition.